# I'm embarrassed to ask this about scaling faces

Tags: modeling, faces, scale

I'm not a smart guy. I haven't been able to google the answer or figure this out on my own.

I placed a cylinder down and scaled it by millimeters to 12.9 mm on x and y, but I also need to change the top end face size to 12.7 mm. I can't figure out how. Unlike the object properties, in edit mode the only property that seems to be available is something called Median. According to google, median just displaces the location of the centerpoint of selected stuff.

All I wanna do is scale a single face of this cylinder by exact millimeters, but so far this software doesn't seem to be capable of that. pressing S and typing anything in just gives wild results.

UPDATE - I gave up on it. I realized that blender isn't as powerful as I had hoped and just did a bunch of extremely time consuming boolean stuff to make 2 cylinder faces into 1 object to get the desired result.
Apparently the folks on the development team have been neglecting the smaller, more important features in favor of professional features that I'll probably never use in my life. No judgement here. It's their software, they can do whatever they want with it.

Comment: Do you have to do it in blender 2.8?
I can show you how it is done in blender 2.79b, the problem is that I don't like 2.8 and I really don't want to learn its Sh..T interface

Comment: You can assign the metric measurements you want, either imperial or metric, or create your own measure. but this is only done in 2.79, and it would be a matter of a couple of minutes that you achieve your goal and do not feel that you are lost

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to start with a 1 base: scale the base cylinder to one in all dimensions.

If you've added a standard cylinder, it should be 2x2x2 meters.

So scale it 0.5 in object mode, then apply scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to have the same in edit mode.

Once done enter edit mode, take the faces you need (maybe the bottom of the cylinder) and scale 12.9: <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>12.9</kbd>

Now select the top part and scale 12.7: <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>12.7</kbd>.

The proportions should be good. Now scale all 0.001 to have it in millimeters.

[image]

In the blend file above, top part is 12.7 and bottom part is 12.9.

Comment: Ok, but that's in object mode, not edit mode, and you scaled the entire thing. I'm not trying to accomplish that. I want to scale **just a single face by exact millimeters**.

Comment: Which face? Could you add some details in your question? If its the top is that to mean the radius should be 12.7?

Comment: I'll give it my best shot to explain this. I placed a cylinder, whose exact dimensions are X: 12.9mm, Y: 12.9mm, Z:25mm.
After doing so, I needed to shrink the end face at the top of the object, so that the bottom of the cylinder is 12.9mm xy, and the top would be 12.7mm xy,

Sort of like an extremely subtle cone shape but the difference is by a mere 0.2 mm.

Comment: The problem being is that the software doesn't seem to be capable of using millimeters in edit mode. When resizing something, it only deals in percentages. I failed math all my life, hombre. I could technicaly divide 12.7 by 12.9 and get 0.984 but that fancy math won't help me in the long run. Eventually I will mess something up during the math and screw the entire model up.

Comment: Either I don't understand which part should be at which dimension, or simply select the wanted part to set it at the wanted dimension. Will add a blend file so that you can check if the answer gives what you want.

Comment: The bottom circle should be 12.9 mm wide, and the top circle should be 12.7
I can achieve only one of those by changing the dimensions of the object in object mode, but once I switch to edit mode, the software stops using millimeters and only uses percentages, so I can't change the other circle to the exact diameter in millimeters that I require.

Comment: Now, technically speaking I solved my problem by creating 2 cylinders, one 12.7 millimeters in diameter and deleting all faces except the top circle and then changing the other cylinder to 12.9 and deleting all faces except the bottom circle. I then joined them and bridged the vertices and edges to make the solid cylinder I wanted with the exact specifications I desire.

I don't want to have to be forced to do that everytime I want to add things to the model. It takes way too much time and won't work all the time. I need to be able to resize faces by exact millimeters.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how you create a tapered cylinder with exact dimensions. You can adjust the height by moving the second circle in z-direction (press "G", then "Z" and type the height in)
[image]

Comment: That's extremely long and drawn out. Are you telling me the software is incapable of performing such a simple task?

Comment: Getting precise measument is difficult in blender, it's not made for that purpose. But I found one more way that is not that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, it is a bit faster:

1. Add the cylinder with the dimensions of the lower face (in your case 12.9 mm on x and y)
   [image: Base cylinder]
2. Move the cylinder in editmode up, so the origin is on the lower face. (Alternatively you can just select the face and move origin to active)
   [image: Clyinder with origin on bottom]
3. Add simple deform modifier set it to taper, select z as axis and set as deform factor: 
   `(d1 / d2) - 1`.
   `d1` is the fist diameter (12.9mm) and `d2` the second diameter (12.7mm) so you have to 
   type: `(12.9mm / 12.7mm) - 1`
   [image: Cylinder with taper]
4. Apply it and your done.
   [image: Tapered Cylinder]